# Product over several previous primes

Tags: prime-numbers, products

I'd like to evaluate

$$\prod_p\left(1-\frac1p\right)$$

over the $k$ largest previous primes $p\le n/2$, where $n$ is the parameter. E.g., if $n=20$ and $k=3$, I'd like the product to be over the 3 previous primes less than or equal to $20/2=10$: namely, $7,5,3$.

The code for the previous prime is

```
PreviousPrime[n_Integer] := Block[{i = n}, While[! PrimeQ[-i]]; i]
SetAttributes[PreviousPrime, Listable];
```

How can I take a product over $k$ previous primes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`NextPrime`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NextPrime.html) to find previous primes too, so you don't need your `PreviousPrime` function.

To get your product, you can use

```
primeprod[n_, k_] := Product[1 - 1/i, {i, NextPrime[n/2, Range[-k, -1]]}]
```

Then

```
primeprod[20, 3]

(* 16/35 *)
```

You can also generalise it by adding the product function as an argument:

```
primeprod2[n_, k_, f_] := Product[f[i], {i, NextPrime[n/2, Range[-k, -1]]}]
```

In which case

```
primeprod2[20, 3, 1 - 1/# &]

(* 16/35 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

One can of course use `PrimePi[]` + `Prime[]` instead:

```
primeprod[n_, k_, f_] :=
With[{p = PrimePi[n/2]}, Apply[Times, f[Prime[Range[p - k + 1, p]]]]]

primeprod[20, 3, 1 - 1/# &]
   16/35
```